# How to capture hand gestures (not touch) on android app?

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app that captures hand gestures without touching the screen. What kind of sensors will I have to use? I don't want camera detection, that's too battery consuming. Will proximity sensor be of any help? How can I even access these sensors? Please, need help here in respect of coding.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find **a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: You mean something like this: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/floating-touch/ ? That was done with device driver changes for a particular touch screen sensor, which isn't something you can do with an app.

Comment: @ jbutler483, Ok how about I require a code? I googled but didn't find anything that's why I came here.

Comment: @ Michael , yes i require something like that. It must be possible to do with an app I'm sure.